# Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string /wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1045

Tags: php, wordpress

I got the following error upon trying to save the "general" settings page on Wordpress admin :

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home1/xxxxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1045

Which is

```
function wp_check_invalid_utf8( $string, $strip = false ) {
$string = (string) $string;

if ( 0 === strlen( $string ) ) {
    return '';
}
```

After researching the problem, I have done all of the following:

Deactivated all plugins (error persists)
Changed to default
   WordPress theme (error persists)
Reinstalled current WordPress
   version (error persists)
Checked Options tables in phpMyAdmin, no
   fishy strings exist Compared Options table between the site with and
   without the error, they seem identical 
Run the WP-Optimize plugin

here is the output of this

```
var_dump($string); 
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
exit;
```

https://anotepad.com/notes/hdhp8y

P.s : I am using bluehost.

Thanks